# How to sent a POST request with form-data and parameters in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, curl, plsql, http-headers, multipartform-data

I'm trying to call REST WebService in PL/SQL but it doesn't work. I get this error:

> `Content-type must be multipart/form-data`

Here is what I have:

```
DECLARE
  req   UTL_HTTP.REQ;
  resp  UTL_HTTP.RESP;
  value VARCHAR2(1024);  -- URL to post to
  v_url VARCHAR2(200) := 'http://local/api/ws';
  -- Post Parameters
  v_param VARCHAR2(500) := 'art=11111\&qty=1'; 
  v_param_length NUMBER := length(v_param);
BEGIN
  req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST (url=> v_url, method => 'POST');
  UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
  UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (r      =>  req,
                       name   =>  'Content-Type',
                       value  =>  'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=/');
  UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (r      =>   req,
                       name   =>   'Content-Length',
                       value  =>   v_param_length);
  UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT (r      =>   req,
                       data   =>   v_param); 

     resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
  LOOP
    UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(resp, value, TRUE);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(value);
  END LOOP;
  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
    UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
END;
```

Here is an example with CURL :

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "art=11111" -F "qty=1" http://local/api/ws
```

This example works fine with curl but i don't know why it doesn't in PL/SQL.
Can you help me ?

Comment: Related, but no solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925278/oracle-utl-http-post-encoding-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use a POST with GET query like you do in the URL...

It looks quite difficult to do what you expect. Here is some input from [Ask Tom](http://dba-oracle.com/t_using_utl_http_for_uploading_into_oracle_.htm):

The idea is to generate the  post text, including a specific "boundary", which will look like this:

> ```
> POST /path/to/script.php HTTP/1.0
> Host: example.com
> Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x
> Content-Length: $requestlen
>
> --AaB03x
> content-disposition: form-data; name="field1"
>
> $field1
> --AaB03x
> content-disposition: form-data; name="field2"
>
> $field2
> --AaB03x
> content-disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="$filename"
> Content-Type: $mimetype
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> $binarydata
> --AaB03x--
> ```

There is also [same issue developed](https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2016/03/21/utl_http-and-a-multipartform-data-request-body/) here with lots of code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I use a similar procedure with POST method at the http request, however I'd set header like:

```
UTL_HTTP.set_header( v_http_request, 
                     'Content-Type', 
                     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' );
```

Be aware also that, if the web-service site implements a security certificate, your DBA must create a wallet server-side, and before opening the request you should invoke that wallet:

```
utl_http.set_wallet('file:<your wallet file route>', '<your pass>');
```

More on Wallets can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asowalet.htm#i1009041)